# setup file for window application

Tags: windows, installation

I created a setup file. It is working fine, but I want an image for my setup. When I installed the setup in any system I want some images on my setup. Help me, thank u.

Comment: Which setup tools did you use? With "setup file" you mean ".msi"?

Comment: yes it is .msi. help me Mr.Manrico Corazzi

Comment: yes i got it Mr. Manrico Corazzi. in solution explorer right click on u r project select property. there u can find the icon option there u can change the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will tell you how to do it in Visual Studio. To change the setup.exe icon you can do the following:

- Build your setup project
- Open the setup.exe file use just build, File -> Open -> File
- Right click the Icon node in the file explorer window and choose the Add Resource
- Import the icon your want in the popup dialog, and make sure the ID of the icon is the smallest one.

Comment: u told to open the setup.exe how can i open Ekaterina

Comment: is it in soulution explorer or in any place(setup.exe)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269897/is-it-possible-to-change-the-setup-exe-and-setup-msi-icons-to-a-different-icon

There is already a threat for your problem. You can check it out.

Comment: Also this one: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10101602/how-to-change-default-exe.aspx

Comment: all links u send is contain same as what u r given for my problem

Comment: yes i got it Ekaterina. in solution explorer right click on u r project select property. there u can find the icon option there u can change the icon.

Comment: aaagh.. that's what you couldn't understand! Damn! Now I got it! I am sorry for the delay reply now. I am glad you figured out your problem!